# Linux cron спамит выполнением скрипта

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron, crontab

Сервер  `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`
Задача в corn записана след образом

```
sudo crontab -e
* 23 * * * cd /path/to/dir && /path/to/python/env/python3 /path/to/dir/one_day.py
```

Скрипт собирает статистику из репозитироия git, скрипт исправен и рабоатет, но cron вместо одиночного выполнения спамит данной командой 1 раз в минуту в течении часа

логи забиты цекличными сообщениями

```
Oct 18 23:40:02 MYSERVERD CRON[3034542]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 18 23:41:01 MYSERVERD CRON[3034584]: (root) CMD (cd /path/to/dire && /path/to/python/env/python3 /path/to/dire/one_day.py)
Oct 18 23:41:01 MYSERVERD CRON[3034583]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 18 23:42:01 MYSERVERD CRON[3034624]: (root) CMD (cd /path/to/dire && /path/to/python/env/python3 /path/to/dire/one_day.py)
```

И так с каждым файлом на python
Файлы отрабатывают в окружении крона `env -i /bin/bash --noprofile -norc` шебанг на нужный интрепритатор стоит, возможно ли это из-за того, что в python и linux код 1 имеют разные расшифровки?

Comment: Из-за того, что они что-то выводят. Перенаправьте stdout и stderr в /dev/null или таки установите exim, если хотите получать этот вывод на локальную почту (в /var/mail)

Comment: У вас указано `* 23` - каждая минута 23-го часа. Укажите вместо первой звёздочки конкретную минуту в часе

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog Попробуйте воспользоваться этим советом и почитайте что он вам пришлет. Но вангую у Вас не правильно настроено окружение поскольку кроме того, чтобы перейти в папку нужно как минимум настроить переменные окружения.

Comment: А лучше почитайте про таймеры и сервисы systemd. Это гораздо более гибкий и удобный инструмент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыл указать минуты спасибо @Герман Борисов

```
1 23 * * * cd /path/to/dir && /path/to/python/env/python3 /path/to/dir/one_day.py
```